# How can I add a global stylesheet to Vue 3 Custom Elements?

Tags: html, css, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

I am trying to use [defineCustomElement](https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/web-components.html#building-custom-elements-with-vue) from Vue 3 to make Single File Components into custom elements.

However when I try to import a local stylesheet to the elements I get the error message: `Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:8081/assets/styles.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.`

I have created a basic Vue 3 project as per [these instructions](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/creating-a-project.html).

In my `main.js` file I have

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

createApp(App).mount('#app')

import { defineCustomElement } from 'vue'
import HelloWorld from './components/HelloWorld.ce.vue'

const HelloWorldElement = defineCustomElement(HelloWorld)
customElements.define('hello-world', HelloWorldElement)
```

and in `HelloWorld.ce.vue` I have added:

```
<style>

@import url("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.css");

a {
  color: #42b983;
}

@import '../assets/styles.css';

</style>
```

in the index file I have replaced the tapp with my component:

```
<hello-world></hello-world>
```

I've also created a basic CSS file under `/src/assets/styles.css`.

The bootstrap import works, as do CSS rules written directly within the `<style>` tags. However the imported local stylesheet will not work - I am sure I have the correct path. I have also tried importing it directly into `main.js` which also doesn't work.

Here is a Code Sandbox with the structure: https://codesandbox.io/s/staging-fire-lox4y9

Is there a way to have one stylesheet that works across multiple custom elements?

Comment: Could you try to use `import "../assets/styles.css";` from the `script` part of your component? Not sure it will solve it though

Comment: @Kapcash I tried and that doesn't work either